Movie/TV series about two investigators finding a single time-travelling guy behind many terrorist attacks worldwide
My memory is a little rusty so this is all the info I have:
There's a scene where a guy and a girl/lady is investigating a major incident (some sort of a terrorist attack). The guy or girl spreads photos of major terrorist attacks worldwide spanning back in the past years. What they uncover is that in every photo, there is this single guy who is always in the background. Their only link to uncover the terrorist attacks is to find this guy/suspect. 
If my memory serves me right, it's some sort of a guy (the suspect) who travels through time or is immortal and controls major global events. The guy looks like John Alexander's character Jarra (or at least in photos that were laid out during their investigation in the movie) in Men in Black II.
Language: English
Year of release: Most likely between 2000+
Movie was in color

Could you be thinking of September from Fringe?

Are you sure they are all terrorist attacks and not just disasters? Because otherwise madmada's answer sounds close. The time-traveller is a time tourist visiting disasters in the past. The movie was a remake based on the story "Vintage Season" published  by Catherine Moore in 1946.

Also, could be an unknown movie called Thrill Seekers or "The Time Shifters" from 1999

A reporter, learning of time travelers visiting 20th century disasters, tries to change the history they know by averting upcoming disasters.






This is the movie I'm looking for! Thank you so much!

glad I could help!

Another possibility might be the Canadian TV series Continuum:

The series centers on the conflict between a group of terrorists from the year 2077 who time travel to Vancouver, BC, in 2012, and a police officer who unintentionally accompanies them. In spite of being many years early, the terrorist group decides to continue its violent campaign to stop corporations of the future from replacing governments, while the police officer endeavours to stop them without revealing to everyone that she and the terrorists are from the future. 

From Wikipedia

It can't be Continuum since they travelled only once and it was to the present day not the past (so no photos of any one of them in past events)

I'm almost tempted to say New-who Series 1 Episode 1, Rose in 2003. Rose and some Internet researcher find evidence that the Doctor is pictured behind every big Historical accident, the Titanic, Krakatoa, etc. As a Time Traveler fascinated with seeing Historical Events first hand, he gets a bad rap.
It's obviously not about a terrorist though, and Eccleston doesn't look like Jarra.


Predestination the movie has a time traveling terrorist that appears at multiple points in history planting bombs.  It is a recent film that fits the time frame of the question. 

Except that the one character is a transgender dressed as a man, not a girl.
